# Which performs better for search in in Adobe AEM, SQL2 or the QueryBuilder?

Tags: aem, jcr

I have to make some queries in AEM and I'm not sure if I should go for the QueryBuilder or SQL2. The queries are not particularly complex. I need to find pages using a date range,tags and resourceType.

Which is the preferred method to make queries in AEM? which one performs better for a big repository.

Comment: May be useful http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__uday-hi_are_thereany.html#forum__uday-hi_are_thereany-composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CRX2/AEM 5.6.1, XPath performance will be generally faster than JCR-SQL2.

In Oak/AEM 6.0, performance will be approximately equivelant as XPath queries are translated into JCR-SQL2.

Comment: yes. Also I asked around my workplace and the consensus seems to be that Xpath is fater than SQL2 when using crx.